# Can I get the point position using remap in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, remap

I have taken a photo `A` using an RGB camera. And I know the position of a point `g` in photo `A`. The camera needs to do a camera calibration. Now I want to know the position of point `g` after calibration. I am using the code as following, but I want to get the point position, not image. How can I do that? Can you give me some advice?

```
initUndistortRectifyMap(
        cameraMatrix,   
        distCoeffs,     
        Mat(),      
        Mat(),      
        Size(640, 480),
        CV_32FC1,      
        map1, map2);  
 remap(A, B, map1, map2, cv::INTER_LINEAR);  

Point2f g = Point2f(...,...);//i want to get the new position of the point not image B
```

Comment: Very related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41703210/inverting-a-real-valued-index-grid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just get coordinates using maps:

x,y - coordinates after (not before),as pasbi correctly noticed in comments, mapping.

(map1(y,x),map2(y,x)) - coordinates before mapping

In other words:

- `map1.at<float>(y,x)` contains source x coordinates for each destination point
  p(x,y).
- `map2.at<float>(y,x)` contains source y coordinates for each destination point
  p(x,y).

See documentation on [remap](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=remap#remap) function.

Comment: Thank you.I have tried it. But in my result,map1 contains transformed y coordinates and map2 contains transformed x?

Comment: Yes, you are right I've mistyped in my answer, must be: map1.at<float>(y,x) because matrix coordinates are (row,col). Corrected now.

Comment: I was doing image rectification(remapping), locating interesting points on a rectified image, and wanted to plot them on the original undistorted image. If I wanted to rotate back the whole image, then I would have to calculate other maps from an inverse homography matrix, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41982442/7851470). But in the case when I want to rotate back just the set of points, not the whole image, I don't need to calculate new maps, I simply need to use old maps from the first rectification process. This took me a while to understand.

Comment: *This answer is not correct*. As stated in the docs you refer to, it is `dst(x, y) = src(map_x(x, y), map_y(x, y))`. Transforming points `dst -> src` is easy (lookup in `map_x` and `map_y`), but the OP wants the other (more natural) direction: `src -> dst`. This is admittingly confusing because `cv::remap` works "inversely" (for numerical stability reasons). I.e., in order to map an image `src -> dst`, you supply a mapping from `dst -> src`. Unfortunately, that's only efficient when transforming many points on a regular grid (i.e. image). Transforming a single random point is pretty difficult.

Comment: Thank you! You are absolutery right, my bad. Fixed answer as possible, may be will found better solution.

Answer (score 1):

undistortPoints() is your need。

```
// src_pts are points in raw(distort) img, rectify_pt_vec are in rectifyImageL
// RL, PL are from stereoRectify()
   cv::undistortPoints(src_pts, rectify_pt_vec, cameraMatrixL, distCoeffL, RL, PL);
```

how to get point in srcimg from dstimg just like pasbi commented below.

Answer (score 0):

best method i found was to recreate a camera matrix, with inverted parameters. work to a certain extent, with like basic images modifications

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `map1` and `map2` from `initUndistortRectifyMap` to find the new position of point `g` after calibration, you'll need to adjust the point using the maps directly. However, as mentioned earlier, there's a more efficient way to get the new position of point `g` using the `undistortPoints` function. But let's focus on updating your original answer first.

Your code to find the new position using the maps would look something like this:

```cpp
// Original point
cv::Point2f g_orig(x, y); // Replace x, y with the coordinates of g

// Convert maps to the correct type if they are not already in CV_16SC2 format
cv::Mat map1_fixed, map2_fixed;
cv::convertMaps(map1, map2, map1_fixed, map2_fixed, CV_16SC2, false);

// Now, you can use the maps to find the new position
cv::Point g_new = map1_fixed.at<cv::Vec2s>(g_orig.y, g_orig.x);

// g_new now contains the new position of point g
```

However, I have to point out that the last line in the code above might not work as expected because `map1` contains fixed-point coordinates, and it should be used with `remap` to remap the whole image. If you want to map a single point, you need to interpolate manually, which is not straightforward.

Therefore, I recommend using `undistortPoints`, which is designed for this purpose:

```cpp
// Original point's coordinates
cv::Point2f g_orig(x, y);

// Make a list containing just your point
std::vector<cv::Point2f> distortedPoints = { g_orig };
std::vector<cv::Point2f> undistortedPoints;

// Undistort the point
cv::undistortPoints(distortedPoints, undistortedPoints, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, cv::noArray(), cameraMatrix);

// Your new, undistorted point
cv::Point2f g_undistorted = undistortedPoints[0];
```

Now, with `g_undistorted`, you have the corrected position for point `g` without having to deal with the whole image. This is less error-prone and more efficient than trying to use the map matrices to adjust the position of a single point.